# Is it possible to make Netbeans suggest variable names like Visual Studio does?

Tags: netbeans, visual-studio-2013

I use Visual Studio since some years ago and I'm a newbie using Netbeans 8.0.1. 
I LOVE this feature in Visual Studio (screenshot taken from VS 2013 Express):

[image: awesome Visual Studio 2013 Express :D :D <3 <3]

Visual Studio suggests variables' and methods' names while I'm writting. Is it possible to have this feature in Netbeans?

Comment: It might be possible through an addon but that functionality would have to be developed.

Comment: @Ramhound: What a shame on Netbeans! Any CaSe SenSitive language IDE should have this feature!

Comment: @Ramhound: I found it! see the answer :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it!!

Go to Tools->Options->Code Completion->Java. Check "Auto Pop-Up on typing any Java identifier part" and "Subword Completion":

[image]

Works on Netbeans 8.0.1. Enjoy!